# linQ to lambda translation not working in linQpad4

Tags: c#, linqpad

I am using LinQPad4 for my first time. I have run one of the LinQ query examples in the program,and when I press the Lambda bottom , the program doesn't show the query transformed into Lambda, can anyone  help me please?

```
var words = from word in "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog".Split() 
            orderby word.ToUpper() 
            select word; 
var duplicates = from word in words 
                 group word.ToUpper() by word.ToUpper() 
                 into g 
                 where g.Count() > 1 
                 select new { g.Key, Count = g.Count() };
words.Dump(); 
duplicates.Dump();
```

Comment: What query did you try?

Comment: @PeterSmithvar words =
 from word in "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog".Split()
 orderby word.ToUpper()
 select word;
 
var duplicates =
 from word in words
 group word.ToUpper() by word.ToUpper() into g
 where g.Count() > 1
 select new { g.Key, Count = g.Count() }; 
 
words.Dump();
duplicates.Dump();

Answer (score 5):

If it's a local query, you'll need to insert `.AsQueryable()` into the query so that an expression tree is generated. This is explained in the built-in sample, **A Note on AsQueryable**

```
var names = new[] { "Tom", "Dick", "Harry", "Mary", "Jay" }.AsQueryable();

// AsQueryable() doesn't change the result of the query. The effect it has it to populate 
// the λ tab below—so you can see how the query translates into lambda (fluent) syntax.
// To illustrate, press F5 to run the following:
(
    from n in names
    where n.Length > 3
    orderby n descending
    select n.ToUpper()
)
.Dump ("Click the λ button - notice the translation to fluent syntax");
```

Comment: I am afraid LinQPad4 doesn't accept the syntax of                 var names = new[] { "Tom", "Dick", "Harry", "Mary", "Jay" }.AsQueryable(); It says there's a closing parenthesis missing,I've checked this query in Visual Studio 2012 where it has no syntax errors. So I can't run the query

Comment: @Goldffy: you'll have to switch the Language to "C# Statements" to run this query.